# I have just started coding and when I type Pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0; it gives me error. I couldn't know how to do it right, where's my problem?

Tags: xcode, solidity, pragma

I have just started learn coding and I couldn't know something that when I type
Pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0; it gives me error.
I couldn't know how to do it right :(

Thank you so much in advance :)
Hala

Comment: What is the error message? Are you writing the expression as `Pragma` (capital `P`) or `pragma` (lowercase)?

Comment: I wrote it as (p) not capital and this was the error message. Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see spdx.org for more information.*

It's a warning unrelated to the `pragma` statement.

The compiler recommends you to state a license under which you want others to use your code.

It should be placed on the first line, before the `pragma` statement.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;
```